# How to pass value of the parameter ' x_duplicate_window ' while using AuthorizeNet?

Tags: c#, .net, authorize.net

I have been using AuthorizeNet.dll ( https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-dotnet ) for last 6 months, it is working great! Recently I am getting following error for few transactions :

"A duplicate transaction has been submitted"
I do research online and found the following link that explain nicely
https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A425&actp=LIST

My question is: How can I pass value for the parameter 'x_duplicate_window' once I call the following method, CustomerGateway.cs -> `public IGatewayResponse AuthorizeAndCapture(Order order)`?
Or do I need to modify something inside the `AuthorizeAndCapture` method? 
Or do I need to modify something inside the HttpXmlUtility.cs->`ANetApiResponse Send(ANetApiRequest apiRequest)`

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Are you configuring the SDK to use AIM?  It appears so, but you didn't explicitly state.

Comment: Nevermind, I see you're using CIM...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to modify the SDK code. It provides an API for CIM "extraOptions" via the `Order.ExtraOptions` property (which is itself an access point for AIM options not present by default in the CIM SOAP messages).  E.g.:

```
Order order = ...
order.ExtraOptions = "x_duplicate_window=0"; // integer seconds, 28800 (8 hour) max; see AIM documentation
// (from comments) if you need to include multiple "extras", the delimiter is '&'
order.ExtraOptions = "x_duplicate_window=0&x_customer_ip=100.0.0.1";
```

Comment: You almost there, I do not see property ExtraOptions exist in CIM Order class but exist in Utility -> createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest class. 
   var req = new createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest();
   req.ExtraOptions = "x_duplicate_window=0";

Comment: You are correct, my sdk bit older, I checked in last sdk source code. ExtraOptions available here. Thanks Marc

Comment: Also, here is the way If we want to pass  multiple optional values x_customer_ip=100.0.0.1&x_cust_id=Testing Extra Options